# SignalR with Azure causes Bad gateway error 502

Tags: signalr, azure-web-app-service, reactjs.net

I have setup a site on Azure which is causing bad gateway error even though it's working perfectly fine on local machine. Here's the error I am facing:

[image: Error detail description]

Also failed request logs contains the following error:

[image]

SignalR logs are following:

[SignalR Logs](https://1drv.ms/t/s!ArwyU6leHkdXa5CYWQ-ZrHVxfdE)

Comment: Have you tried to enable Web Sockets in your web site settings in the portal? Signalr is supposed to work even without this config but maybe it will help

Comment: @shachar yes web sockets on and .net framework 4.5

Comment: The property EnableDetailedErrors in the  HubConfiguration is set to true?

Comment: @shachar yes it's enabled.

Comment: do you have CORS enabled? also, you didn't censure your website name completely

Comment: @Nikola.Lukovic CORS is not enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I was adding the following line Startup.cs Configuration method:

```
GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.UseSqlServer(sqlConnectionString)
```

But SQL Azure doesn't support it and that's what was causing the issue.